# Solving integral with two big polynomials, need help figuring out where I went wrong

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

Been working on this problem for quite a while, and followed as closely along with the other problem just like it and the help I got here as I could, but the answer I got for this is still. Would like some help figuring out where I messed up.

[image]

[image]

Comment: To be honest, that is all pretty unreadable and I don't like your chances of getting a detailed answer.  Suggestion: check your answers step by step: first check that your values of $A,B,C,D$ are correct by substituting back and simplifying.  Then check that each individual integral is correct by differentiating.  When you have narrowed down where the error is, if you still can't fix it, post a shorter question.

Comment: @widy401: Partial fractions are correct, looks like something went south with first integration, http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(5+x)%2F(26+%2B+10+x+%2B+x%5E2)

Comment: In integral 2, you wrote 20 instead of 25.

Comment: @ user84413: Thank you so much! Final answer is not coming out correctly.

Comment: I think you just need to change 87 to 97, and you'll have it.

Comment: Oh oops sorry. I mean it is coming out correctly. I got it.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion :Break into parts,if necessary break into sub-parts.Write equations in complete sentences so you can tell how to put the parts back together. The parts you need are $\int x^n(x^2+5)^{-2}dx $ for $n\in \{0,1,2,3\}.$ For odd $n$  substitute $x^2=y$ and $x dx=(1/2)dy$.